# Mechanisms: What is the difference between the top chemical and bottom chemical on an arrow for a mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I’ve heard the top chemical that is on top of the reaction arrow represents the “first step”, and bottom is “second step” when referring to a mechanism. My question is will the bottom chemical always act as a solution to help aid in the mechanism process *after* the main nucleophile/base on top attacks first.

Example: 2-bromo-3-methylbutane —> (NaOCH3 on top and CH3OH on bottom)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are no strict rules, and the "bottom" chemical might be the solvent, the second step, another reactant that didn't fit in the first row, or something totally different altogether, such as a comment with reaction conditions. Related: [What is meant by the numbers on reagents above and below arrows?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63850)

Comment: I write reaction equations with reagents on top of the arrow, solvents, temperatures, atmosphere and time below. If multiple steps are used then they are numbered to indicate different reactions.

Comment: In your specific example, I would read that as methanol being solvent and sodium methoxide as reagent.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t any hard and fast rule about what is supposed to go above or below the arrow, although reagents tend to go above and solvents tend to go below. Sometimes transformations are performed by subjecting the reactant to a sequence of reaction conditions. In such a case, the conditions are listed numerically above and/or below the reaction arrow.